# PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values after changing everything even with a new

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm doing a simple function in Oracle PL/SQL, I have tried changing everything but I still get the PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values error for the code below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_deptinfo (deptname varchar)
RETURN varchar
is 
get_informacion varchar(1500);

BEGIN

    SELECT
    DISTINCT
    job_history.EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, job_history.department_id, DEPARTMENT_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE
    INTO get_informacion
    FROM DEPARTMENTS
    INNER JOIN JOB_HISTORY ON job_history.department_id = departments.department_id
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES ON job_history.employee_id = employees.employee_id
    WHERE departments.department_name = deptname;
    RETURN (get_informacion);
    
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN RETURN 0;
    
END;
```

Can anybody help, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT job_history.employee_id,
                first_name,
                last_name,
                job_history.department_id,
                department_name,
                start_date,
                end_date
INTO   get_informacion
```

i.e. you're trying to insert **7 values** into **1 scalar variable**, and it won't work.

As you declared `get_informacion` as quite a large string, did you - by any chance - meant to *concatenate* those 7 values? For example,

```
 SELECT DISTINCT job_history.employee_id  ||', '||
                first_name                ||', '||
                last_name                 ||', '||
                job_history.department_id ||', '||
                department_name           ||', '||
                start_date                ||', '||
                end_date
INTO   get_informacion
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm trying to get the information of all those columns to be showed when runing the function providing a string to the variable deptname. So I'm looking just to get all that information showed

Comment: @EmmanuelGutiérrez, Littlefoot explained it.  You either have to concatenate all the values into one string, or create a procedure, and return all the values separately as OUT parameters.   Since you don't show how you plan on calling this function or what to do with the results, it is impossible to provide any other answer.